git filter repo, can't find python on windows, despite it being in the path and being able to run python from cmd
Similar to this, but not the same issue (all the steps prior were followed, python is provably on path) git filter repo - Python was not found - but it's installed
Basically I try to run git filter-repo, and while the script is recgonized, python cannot be found, saying:
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

despite being able to run python:
C:\Users\user\Documents>python
Python 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Why can't it find python?

Related.

Modern versions of python do not install a "python3" executable for windows.  This makes some sense, as windows doesn't have the python3/python legacy issues, but for systems that do have this issue (linux), it means using
#!/usr/bin/env python3

was the best cross platform option to use the latest version of python 3.x for that platform, as python would default to python 2.x on some systems.  Unfortunately because the windows installation of things like python 3.11+ don't do this, it means that this call will fail, since there's no python3 executable in the Python's windows executable path.  The authors of the git-filter-repo script could fix this in the future, but for now, if you're on windows, the easiest solution is to edit the git-filter-repo script (not the .py file) and remove the 3 from python3:
#!/usr/bin/env python

provided you actually put python in your path.  To robustly handle python finding on more systems, the following may be needed: shebang env preferred python version
